# foreign key per table versus type and foreign key?

Tags: c#, database-design, entity-framework-core

we have a table and this table contains reminder data from different tables.

Method 1 - There are 2 critical columns in the table;

```
// RelationTable contains of a minimum of 12 tables.
public enum RelationTable : byte
{
    TableA = 1,
    TableB = 2,
    ...
}

public class Reminder {
   // Represents in which table the data is stored
   [Required]
   public RelationTable RelationTable { get; set; }

   // Primary key in the table where data is stored
   [Required]
   public Guid RelationId { get; set; }

   public DateTime Reminderdate { get; set; }

   ...
}
```

For example, we want to fetch some data in TableA, we will join TableA using the sql or ef core;

```
dbContext.Reminders.Where(x => x...)
.Join(dbContext.TableA, x => x.RelationId, c => c.Id, (x, c) => new { c.XColumn });
```

But this method is tiring and quite costly. As you can imagine, there are also more complicated situations.

Method 2 - foreign key per table;

```
public class Reminder {
   // Represents in which table the data is stored
   [Required]
   public RelationTable RelationTable { get; set; }

   public Guid? TableAId { get; set; }
   public TableA TableA { get; set; }

   public Guid? TableBId { get; set; }
   public TableB TableB { get; set; }

   public DateTime Reminderdate { get; set; }

   ...
}
```

For example, we want to fetch some data in TableA, we will join TableA using ef core, it's easy;

```
dbContext.Reminders.Where(x => x...).Select(x => new { x.TableA.XColumn });
```

As you can see this method is easier than method 1. But this method can get complicated too. And the number of columns will always increase..

Which one is correct? Or what should be right solution for this situations?

Thanks.

Comment: Option 3: Separate `Remainder` table per each table which needs such information. Standard FK relationship (which is impossible with your method #1), easy access via navigation property. Base class (not entity) can be used to define/reuse the all the `Reminder` properties except the FK/navigation property.

Comment: @IvanStoev -if I understood you correctly- if I shred the `Reminder` table then wouldn't it be more difficult? If table `Reminder` disappears then I need to run queries(with ef) per table. Or I may need to write `union` queries.

Comment: Do you really need such polymorphic queries? Usually people which have this issue don't really need such, just trying to minimize the number of database tables, which makes to sense nowadays.